# jQuery load more data on scroll not loading more data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, scroll

I am working on a jQuery load more data scroll, which when I click on category link it will sort the data based on that category I click, which is working well. It only load first six how can I fix this issue.

```
index.php
<a href="index.php?where=category1">Category</a>

<div class="container"> 
        <div class="row" id="results"></div>    
        <div id="loader_image" align="center">
            <img src="loader.gif" alt="" width="50"> 
        </div>
        <div id="loader_message" align="center"></div>          
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    //For The Scroll
    var busy = false;
    var limit = 6
    var offset = 0;
    var where = '<?php if(isset($_GET["where"])) {echo $_GET['where'];} else {echo ' ';} ?>';

    function displayRecords(lim, off, where) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          async: false,
          url: "<?php echo(link);?>getrecords.php",
          data: "limit=" + lim + "&offset=" + off + "&where=" + where,
          cache: false,
          beforeSend: function() {
            $("#loader_message").html("").hide();
            $('#loader_image').show();
          },
          success: function(html) {
            $("#results").append(html);
            $('#loader_image').hide();
            if (html == "") {
              $("#loader_message").html('<button class="btn btn-default" type="button">No more records.</button>').show()
            } else {
              // $("#loader_message").html('<button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Loading please wait...</button>').show();
              $('#loader_image').show();

            }
            window.busy = false;
          }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        // start to load the first set of data
        if (busy == false) {
          busy = true;
          // start to load the first set of data
          displayRecords(limit, offset, where);
        }


        $(window).scroll(function() {
          // make sure u give the container id of the data to be loaded in.
          if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $("#results").height() && !busy) {
            busy = true;
            offset = limit + offset;
            where = '<?php if(isset($_GET["where"])) {echo $_GET['where'];} else {echo ' ';} ?>';

            // this is optional just to delay the loading of data
            setTimeout(function() { displayRecords(limit, offset, where); }, 500);

            // you can remove the above code and can use directly this function
            // displayRecords(limit, offset);

          }
        });
      });
</script>




getrecords.php

$where = '';
    if(isset($_GET['where'])){
        $search = str_replace('-',' ', $_GET['where']);
        $where .= "WHERE category LIKE '%$search%'";
    }

$limit = (intval($_GET['limit']) != 0 ) ? $_GET['limit'] : 6;
$offset = (intval($_GET['offset']) != 0 ) ? $_GET['offset'] : 0;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users {$where} ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset";
try {
      $stmt = $user->runQuery($sql);
      $stmt->execute();
      $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
if (count($results) > 0) {
  foreach ($results as $res) {
?>

        <div class="col-sm-4 my-4 text-center">
              <div class="card">
                  <img class="rounded-circle img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
                  <h3><?php echo ucwords($res['name']); ?></h3>

                  <small><?php echo $res['category']; ?></small>
              </div>
        </div>

<?php   
  }
}
?>
```

see below preview it image of the issue
[image]

Comment: Please add  your code as code not as pictures of code. I don't think anyone feels like re-typing that to try to help you.

Comment: I have done that.

Comment: Quick note, `if (busy == false)` can be shortened to `if(!busy)`.

Comment: Also, `async: false,` is very very bad.  If you are having to use that then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: That is not the default value.  The default behavior for ajax is to be asynchronous.  In fact, that is what the first 'a' in ajax is for.  If `async: false` then you are forcing it to be synchronous which is counter to the point of ajax.  It will also cause the UI to freeze until the request returns.  The only 1 time I ever use that property is if I am doing an before-unload and I was to prevent the browser from leaving the page too early.

Comment: oops I had it backwards in my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the loading icon is never removed check the console for any errors. You're setting the loading icon to be shown in the `beforeSend` function but have no `error` property in the ajax handler.

Remove `$("#results").append(html);` from the top of your `success: function(html) { .. }` and move it into the `else` portion of your `if` statement. You do this so you're not attempting to append an empty string, or an unwanted string, for no reason and we have finer control over it via our `if/else` logic.

You'll also want to remove `$('#loader_image').show()` from the `else` statement. You're re-showing it even though the ajax call has been processed successfully.

See the cleaned up `success` function below.

```
success: function(html) {
  $('#loader_image').hide();
  if (html == "") {
    $("#loader_message").html('<button class="btn btn-default" type="button">No more records.</button>').show()
  } else {
    $("#results").append(html);    
  }
  window.busy = false;
}
```

New ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  async: false,
  url: "<?php echo(link);?>getrecords.php",
  data: "limit=" + lim + "&offset=" + off + "&where=" + where,
  cache: false,
  beforeSend: function() {
    $("#loader_message").html("").hide();
    $('#loader_image').show();
  },
  success: function(html) {
    $('#loader_image').hide();
    if (html == "") {
      $("#loader_message").html('<button class="btn btn-default" type="button">No more records.</button>').show()
    } else {
       $('#results').append(html);
    }
    window.busy = false;
  },
  error: function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    $('#loader_image').hide();
    $('#loader_message').html('There was an error processing your request.').show();
  }
});
```